# How can I build a way to check if a page is updated to include a keyword?

Tags: javascript

I want to make this a chrome extension that can send me an email each time a webpage is changed to include the specific word(s).

I feel maybe it can be done via query but not sure how (never did this before). I'm relatively new to coding so not sure how to check once a day and go about this. Perhaps you can guide me in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: what does `via query` mean? `how to check once a day` - depends on the nature of the web page. It could be as easy as fetching the url and checking for your words, but if the page is created using front end code, you'd have to open the page in a new tab and inject content script to perform the search

Comment: Chrome extensions usually execute in the context of accessing the webpage. If you want something to run periodically, it would be better to do it as a batch job, not a browser extensions. On Linux you use `cron` to run it, on Windows you use the Task Scheduler.

Comment: @Bravo please ignore query. Let's just use public Crunchbase company pages as example where you want to get notified every time it get's updated with new "investment" (imagine that's the keyword)

Comment: @Barmar I imagined the extension would be used to track the page but it can be stored elsewhere. Just not sure how to go abut this

Comment: You also can't send email from the browser, so that's another reason why a browser extension is the wrong place to do this. Write a shell script that uses `curl`. You can save the result in a file, then the next time you can compare the result with the saved version.